# Tracker.Enabled returns false

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-analytics

I'm trying to figure out why `Tracker.Enabled` is returning false in my Sitecore installation. I have checked the config files and both `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` are set to `true`. I have tested to change their values but that didn't help.

I've checked the source code for `Tracker.Enabled` property in dotPeek:

```
public static bool Enabled
{
  get
  {
    if (!XdbSettings.Tracking.Enabled)
      return false;
    return (bool) (Context.get_Items().get_Item("ANALYTICS_DISABLE_INITIALIZATION") ?? (object) true);
  }
  set
  {
    Context.get_Items().set_Item("ANALYTICS_DISABLE_INITIALIZATION", (object) value);
  }
}
```

`XdbSettings.Tracking.Enabled` property basically reads configuration so it should return true. My only guess is that the property is set to `false` somewhere but could not find any place in `Sitecore.Analytics` assembly.

Anyone has any idea why `Tracker.Enabled` could return false?

Comment: Check if your license is xDB enabled. See also https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4767/is-it-possible-to-use-any-personalisation-rules-without-xdb

Comment: It is xDB enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Too late to answer, but here is my answer anyway. Check the log when the site boots up for the first time.
[You should see output like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Fet.png)

Even if it's set to true and tracking is not working, give yourself a try by putting log level to debug and you should find this
[postsession output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYzJV.png).